# Export SPWeb SharePoint 2010 weird dll error

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010

Ik get a weird error when running the following command:

```
PS C:\> Export-SPWeb -Identity http://dfz-85:81/ -Path "C:\temp.cmp"
```

This is the error i get, the .dll file keeps changing every time i try the command.

```
Export-SPWeb : Could not find file 'C:\Users\cmsadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\mlilsk
gt.dll'.
At line:1 char:13
+ Export-SPWeb <<<<  -Identity http://dfz-vm85:81/ -Path "C:\tmep.cmp"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...CmdletExportWeb:
   SPCmdletExportWeb) [Export-SPWeb], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletExportWeb
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would love to know how this was resolved

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same error. Could not find the reason but could successfully export from central admin > backup restore option.

Answer (score 1):

Came across this issue and eventually resolved it. Not sure what the actual solution was but the steps I took were:

1. Add logged in user as [SP Shell Admin on the content database](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607596.aspx) you're exporting/importing from/to
2. Close the SharePoint 2010 Management Shell window
3. Reopen the SharePoint 2010 Management Shell window with the Import system modules option (right click on the icon in Windows 7)

Comment: fixed simply by opening a new powershell session

Answer (score 0):

I ended up avoiding the issue and exporting/importing with SharePoint designer.

This can only be done under "All Files" and on each individual file, afaik.